# How to binding to relative source

Tags: binding, relativesource

Do you see any problem with my codes when I tried to bind a check box inside a DataGrid to a public property of a the View Model which is the data context of the user control.

thanks,

Jdang

```
 <Custom:DataGrid    ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" 
                                AlternatingRowBackground="AliceBlue"  
                                AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                                MaxHeight="250"                          
                                CanUserAddRows="False" 
                                CanUserDeleteRows="False" >
                <Custom:DataGrid.Columns>                       
                    <Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                            <WrapPanel>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding  Path=IsCheckAll, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, 
                                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>                                                                       
                                <TextBlock>Select<LineBreak/>UnSelect</TextBlock>
                            </WrapPanel>                               
                        </Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Selected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

The usercontrol you try to find, is (I assume as it's not in the code snippet) in the logical tree.
The binding is in the template which means that it's part of the visual tree. As they don't have a connection you cannot find it.

Comment: Martin, All the controls on that form belong to the top level ancestor which is a user control. To me, the binding engine should be able to walks up on the logical tree and find that user control. I must missed something that made the binding failed.